# VB.Net Importing CSV File to SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, csv, import

So, I need help figuring out how to make this work and would love to start a conversation with other VB Experts.

I have a CSV file that is dumped into an import folder every hour.  I have written a VB application that scans that folder, picks up the CSV file and imports it into a SQL database.  No problems there.

The problem comes when trying to query the data in SQL.  All of the important data that I need is in one field, here is a modified example of the field contents:

```
Successful Write by DOMAIN\USERLOGIN on /SOMENETWORKSHARE/FOLDER/MyFolder/USERLOGIN/DesktopBackUp/log.txt
```

So basically I need a way to split the above line into multiple fields and it needs to happen at the time of the SQL import.

`Successful Write` "is the event"  Field 1

by "doesn't ever change could be used as a separator"

`DOMAIN/USERLOGIN`  "DOMAIN doesn't change but userlogin will"  Field 2

on "doesn't ever change could be used as a separator"

`/SOMENETWORKSHARE/FOLDER/MyFolder/USERLOGIN/DesktopBackUp/` "This is the file path" Field 3

`log.txt` "Filename that's modified" Field 4

Sometimes there's not a Filename, just a file path.

I'm open to suggestions, however, The CSV file doesn't change and I don't have the ability to change the way the file is delivered to me.

Thanks in Advance.

Here is the Database Structure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SACL](
    [Unique ID] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Event ID] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Event Time] [datetime] NULL,
    [Severity] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Workspace] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Headline] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Event] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Username] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Path] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Filename] [varchar](max) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Comment: Google VB **Substring()** OR VB **Regex**. Good luck

Comment: I dont think you mentioned *which* piece of data you want in all that.

Comment: I'm wanting to split that one long field name into 4 fields, I broke them down above.

Comment: Thanks @mxix for the Regex recommendation, that just might work.  I'm going to play with that and see if I can build a pattern and post it.

Comment: You have a number of options: 1. Use VB code to split it on the way in 2. Use SQL expressions to split it on the way in 3. Create a calculated column in your table to split it 4. Create a view over the table that splits the data. I my experience splitting data like this is error prone and you need to be able to adjust the splitting algorithm easily. I first suggest you write some select statements to get the data out using SQL and discover what level of complexity you need to extract the data.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Ideally it would be great if I could modify the CSV file before it hits my Import Process.  Then I wouldn't have to change any of the importer, it would just work.

Comment: You need to transform your data. You can transform it inside a VB import program or you can import it into a staging table and transform it using SQL inside there. Personally I like to avoid needing to compile a program to do work but you're probably more comfortable with VB.

Comment: So you could import into an existing table with 9 fields and run an `UPDATE` statement afterwards to split one field into 4 afterwards. In my experience though, you might find that there are 5,6,7.. even 100 fields bunched up into one field.

Comment: @nick.mcdermaid. This is exactly what I was going to do.  I've actually got about 15 million records I'll have to actually run an update script on, but I haven't been able to get my SQL statement to work right. Let me find the script I had been working on and I'll post it and see what you think.

Comment: @Dcapers I've added an answer along these lines below.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could help you. After call this function, you could use the result to include every single field in another table from your database or something similar.

```
Public Function divideThis(CompleteString As String)

    Dim n As Integer = InStr(CompleteString, " by ")
    Dim Field1 As String = CompleteString.Substring(0, n - 1)

    Dim m As Integer = InStr(CompleteString, " on ")
    Dim Field2 As String = CompleteString.Substring(n + 3, m - n - 4)

    Dim o As Integer = InStrRev(CompleteString, "/")
    Dim Field3 As String = CompleteString.Substring(m + 3, o - m - 3)

    Dim Field4 As String = CompleteString.Substring(o, CompleteString.Length - o)

    Dim fragmented As String() = {Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4}

    Return (fragmented)

End Function
```

Comment: This answer looks well formed

Comment: This is actually great, gave me the 4 pieces of information I needed when i tested it.  So here's an implementation question.  My application reads the csv file and imports it first into a dataset and then I use sqlbulkcopy to import into SQL.  Can this function be used on a column in the dataset to add 4 additional columns before I pass it over to sqlbulkcopy?  Also would I have speed issues with CSV files that have 100K+ records?

Answer (score 0):

OK try this...It will import the CSV file, splitting the required field and merging it as it goes.

I have modified the code to include the RegEx in the LINQ statement to split that field, it will work if there is NO file name BUT there HAS to be a forward slash at the end AND this MUST be the ONLY field (in you CSV file) that contains forward slashes... the reason being is that you are going to lose a field if the forward slash is missing and NO file name OR you will get too many fields if other fields in your csv file contain a forward slash.....

```
Sub Main()  
    Dim regex As Text.RegularExpressions.Regex = New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\d+")  
    Dim readText() As String = File.ReadAllLines("<Path to your CSV file>")  

    Using connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("<DB connection string>")  

        Dim command As SqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand()
        connection.Open()  

        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure  
        command.CommandText = "SP_InsertCSVData"  

        For i As Integer = 0 To readText.Count
            Dim readRecord() As String = readText.ToArray

            Dim CSVData As XElement = New XElement("Root",
                            From str In readText
                            Let fields = Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, "(by|on|\/(?=[^\/]*$))", ",").Split(",")
                            Select New XElement("CSVDataRecord",
                                New XAttribute("Field_1", fields(0)),
                                New XAttribute("Field_2", fields(1)),
                                New XAttribute("Field_3", fields(2)),
                                New XAttribute("Field_4", fields(3)),
                                New XAttribute("Field_5", fields(4)),
                                New XAttribute("Field_6", fields(5)),
                                New XAttribute("Field_7", fields(6)),
                                New XAttribute("Field_8", fields(7))
                            )
                        )

            command.Parameters.Clear()
            command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With
            {
                .ParameterName = "@InputXML",
                .DbType = DbType.Xml,
                .Value = CSVData.CreateReader
            })

            command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Next
    End Using

End Sub
```

Here is the new table...

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[CSV_Import_Table]    Script Date: 06/02/2016 01:55:32 ******/   
SET ANSI_NULLS ON  
GO  

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON  
GO  

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CSV_Import_Table](  
[Field_1] [nvarchar](max) NULL,  
[Field_2] [nvarchar](max) NULL,  
[Field_3] [nvarchar](max) NULL,  
[Field_4] [nvarchar](max) NULL,  
[Field_5] [nvarchar](max) NULL,  
[Field_6] [nvarchar](max) NULL,  
[Field_7] [nvarchar](max) NULL,  
[Field_8] [nvarchar](max) NULL  
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]  

GO
```

And here is the SP...

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_InsertCSVData]    Script Date: 06/02/2016 01:56:20 ******/  
SET ANSI_NULLS ON  
GO  
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON  
GO  
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_InsertCSVData] (@InputXML xml)  
as  
begin  
MERGE  CSV_Import_Table AS main  
USING (select Row.id.value('@Field_1','[nvarchar](MAX)') as Field_1, Row.id.value('@Field_2','[nvarchar](MAX)') as Field_2, Row.id.value('@Field_3','[nvarchar](MAX)') as Field_3, Row.id.value('@Field_4','[nvarchar](MAX)') as Field_4,  Row.id.value('@Field_5','[nvarchar](MAX)') as Field_5, Row.id.value('@Field_6','[nvarchar](MAX)') as Field_6, Row.id.value('@Field_7','[nvarchar](MAX)') as Field_7, Row.id.value('@Field_8','[nvarchar](MAX)') as Field_8  
            from @InputXML.nodes('/Root/CSVDataRecord') as Row(id)) as stage  
ON main.Field_1=stage.Field_1  
WHEN MATCHED THEN  
    UPDATE SET main.Field_1=stage.Field_1, main.Field_2=stage.Field_2, main.Field_3=stage.Field_3, main.Field_4=stage.Field_4 ,   main.Field_5=stage.Field_5 , main.Field_6=stage.Field_6, main.Field_7=stage.Field_7, main.Field_8=stage.Field_8     
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
    INSERT  (Field_1, Field_2, Field_3, Field_4, Field_5, Field_6, Field_7, Field_8) VALUES (stage.Field_1, stage.Field_2, stage.Field_3, stage.Field_4, stage.Field_5, stage.Field_6, stage.Field_7, stage.Field_8);  
end
```

And i'm guessing that you CSV file looks something like this....

Record 1 Field 1, Successful Write by DOMAIN\USERLOGIN on /SOMENETWORKSHARE/FOLDER/MyFolder/USERLOGIN/DesktopBackUp/Log.txt, Field 6, Field 7, Field 8

Comment: As I stated in my original post, I have no control over the CSV file.  The CSV file contains 5 fields that are already comma delimited.  My windows form application, detects a CSV file in the import directory, loads it into a processing Queue, Imports the file into a Dataset and uses SQLBulkCopy to import into the database.  What I need to be able to do is split one of the existing fields into 4 more, so ultimately the database table is going to have 9 fields after it is imported.

Comment: OK that a little more clear.... Well, your going to have to split the elements of that field any way before you insert it into separate columns of your table... why not just simply split the data as [and when] you display it to the user....ie, when querying the data in SQL, simply split the retuned string from that field up using something like Miguel Baena function 'divideThis'example, passing in that field as his 'CompleteString' which will then return an array 'fragmented' containing the 4 fields that you need.....

Answer (score 0):

Here's a select that you should be able to run over your table to test.

Replace the `FROM ( .... ) as tbl` bit with your real table

You can see that the expressions in the select are pretty ugly and unwieldy so have a think about whether you are happy maintaining this

There is a `WHERE` at the end to stop invalid data getting in. If data with missing delimiters gets in, then indexes will end up being negative and you'll get all kinds of errors.

With these kinds of things data quality is always an issue. So we don't want to compound that by assuming the domain will have the same name forever, or assuming that you'll only ever import data from one domain.

So you need to run this against your table, see if it works. If so the next step is:

- take the file name out of the path
- change into an update

That should be straightforward

```
SELECT 
SRC,
LEFT(SRC,CHARINDEX(' by ',SRC)) AS Operation,
SUBSTRING(
    SRC,
    CHARINDEX(' by ',SRC)+4,
    CHARINDEX(' on ',SRC) - CHARINDEX(' by ',SRC)-4
    ) AS LoginName,

RIGHT(
    SRC,  
    LEN(SRC) - CHARINDEX(' on ',SRC)-4
) AS FullPath,

REVERSE(LEFT(
    REVERSE(SRC),
    CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(SRC))-1)
    ) AS PathAndFileName
FROM 
(
SELECT 'Successful Write by DOMAIN\USERLOGIN on /SOMENETWORKSHARE/FOLDER/MyFolder/USERLOGIN/DesktopBackUp/log.txt' AS SRC
UNION ALL
SELECT 'some invalid stuff' AS SRC
) as tbl
WHERE SRC LIKE '% by %\% on %/%'
```

An update statement that applies this would be:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[SACL]
SET 
[Event]=
LEFT(Headline,CHARINDEX(' by ',Headline)),
[Username] = 
SUBSTRING(
    Headline,
    CHARINDEX(' by ',Headline)+4,
    CHARINDEX(' on ',Headline) - CHARINDEX(' by ',Headline)-4
    ),
[Path] = 
SUBSTRING(
    Headline,
    CHARINDEX(' by ',Headline)+4,
    CHARINDEX(' on ',Headline) - CHARINDEX(' by ',Headline)-4
    ),

[FileName]=
REVERSE(LEFT(
    REVERSE(Headline),
    CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(Headline))-1)
    )
WHERE 
-- Only update rows that fit the pattern
Headline LIKE '% by %\% on %/%'
-- Only update rows that haven't been processed
AND ([Event] IS NULL  OR [Event]  = '')
```

Please note:

- I don't know which field contains the full string. I assumed `Headline`
- I suggest you standardise on the contents of the `Event` field. NULL = Not processed and blank means something else (processed but couldn't work it out)
- I also suggest you add an `ImportedDate` and `ProcessedDate` field which is of type datetime. `ImportedDate` has a `default` of `GETDATE()` which means this is the datetime the record was imported. ProcessedDate should be updated by the UPDATE statement to be `GETDATE()` and this tells you when the record was updated.

Comment: This is beautiful, works awesome!!!  However one question, on the last PathandFileName, You have it populating this field based on everything to the right of the last '/', my audit logs will give me either a directory path or a filename, one line would be '/PATH/TO/Accounting' and the next would be '/PATH/TO/Accounting/Filename.xlsx'.  Would there be any way to ignore anything other than a filename in this field?

Comment: Glad it helped. If you want to _exclude_ a pathname from the records you change your where to `WHERE SRC LIKE '% by %\% on %/%.%'`

Comment: Once thats all good you change the `SELECT` into an `UPDATE` and update pre existing fields after you import the data. You can wrap all of this in a stored procedure and call the stored procedure from your import app. and if your rules change you can change the stored procedure instead of recompiling your app

Comment: Excellent. I will add the update statement but you need to post your table DDL (data definition language - the create table statement)

Comment: Sure that would be great.  Question, if I only want to update the database only if the [Event] is Null or Empty, how could we do that?

Comment: I included the table structure in the original question above.  It was too big for comments.